# How to replace NA values in dataframe's column with my own values in R?

Tags: r

I want to replace NA values in this column "Outlet_Size" with its particular modes w.r.t other column "Outlet_Type"

if it helps, I am using [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kyanyoga/sample-sales-data?datasetId=435&sortBy=dateRun&tab=profile)

edit:

```
> dput(rbind(head(data[is.na(data$Outlet_Type),]),head(data[!is.na(data$Outlet_Type),])))
structure(list(Item_Identifier = c("FDW58", "FDW14", "NCN55", 
"FDQ58", "FDY38", "FDH56"), Item_Weight = c(20.75, 8.3, 14.6, 
7.315, 12.6956333687566, 9.8), Item_Fat_Content = c("Low Fat", 
"Regular", "Low Fat", "Low Fat", "Regular", "Regular"), Item_Visibility = c(0.007564836, 
0.038427677, 0.099574908, 0.015388393, 0.118599314, 0.063817206
), Item_Type = c("Snack Foods", "Dairy", "Others", "Snack Foods", 
"Dairy", "Fruits and Vegetables"), Item_MRP = c(107.8622, 87.3198, 
241.7538, 155.034, 234.23, 117.1492), Outlet_Identifier = c("OUT049", 
"OUT017", "OUT010", "OUT017", "OUT027", "OUT046"), Outlet_Establishment_Year = c(1999L, 
2007L, 1998L, 2007L, 1985L, 1997L), Outlet_Size = c("Medium", 
NA, NA, NA, "Medium", "Small"), Outlet_Location_Type = c("Tier 1", 
"Tier 2", "Tier 3", "Tier 2", "Tier 3", "Tier 1"), Outlet_Type = c("Supermarket Type1", 
"Supermarket Type1", "Grocery Store", "Supermarket Type1", "Supermarket Type3", 
"Supermarket Type1")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
> modes
  Outlet_Type        mode
  <chr>             <chr>
1 Grocery Store     Small
2 Supermarket Type1 Small
3 Supermarket Type2 Medium
4 Supermarket Type3 Medium
```

I tried,

```
> data2$Outlet_Size[which(is.na(data2$Outlet_Size))]<-modes$Outlet_Size[data$Outlet_Type == modes$Outlet_Type]
Warning messages:
1: In data$Outlet_Type == modes$mode :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In data2$Outlet_Size[which(is.na(data2$Outlet_Size))] <- modes$Outlet_Size[data$Outlet_Type ==  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

but it doesn't seem to work as intended. However, it does remove NA values by 2 every time I run this

```
> sum(is.na(data))
[1] 1606
> sum(is.na(data2))
[1] 1600
```

Comment: your lhs indexing should have the same length as rhs length.  instead of calculatin gthe `NA` in the whole data, check for the NA in the particular column `sum(is.na(data2$Outlet_Size))` and `sum(data$Outlet_Type == modes$Outlet_Type)`.  In addition, `==` returns `NA` where there are NA, So you may use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: please provide sample data that does not require us to set up an account on kaggle in order to see, perhaps `dput(head(data2,20))`, making sure that that sample includes some `NA` values that need to be replaced (and some values that need to not be replaced).

Comment: the fact that it's a warning means the code is still working, although possibly not as intended.

Comment: it sounds like this may to better as a `merge` and coalesce (`ifelse(is.na(z.x), z.y, z.x)`).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, I'll keept that in mind from now on. and I edited it as you said.

Comment: Thanks for the `data`, but ... none of it is `NA`. If you are asking how to replace `NA` values in data, it's best to provide examples and counter-examples, where _some_ (not all) of your rows contain the condition you want to fix. Also please verify (either in the sample data itself as another column, or as clear text afterwards) what the correct values should be.

Comment: Perhaps the output from `dput(rbind(head(data[is.na(data$Outlet_Type),]),head(data[!is.na(data$Outlet_Type),])))`?